# Are there any white people in the Bible?

Tags: translation-philosophy, referent-identification

Every few months, a photo of a protestor's sign makes the rounds on social media; the sign says, "There are no white people in the Bible. Take all the time you need with this." Reliably, there are comments on the photo which claim that various Biblical characters were white, particularly Roman characters. For example, see [this conversation on Mastodon yesterday](https://mastodon.social/@juglugs/111914718493407001).

**According to the Bible, are there any white people in the Bible?** I'm not asking whether Romans were white in general, but whether any specific characters are identified as white in original texts. Adjusting or accounting for translation is expected, since the modern conception of whiteness is only a few centuries old.

Comment: I apologize for the blunt question, but it's not my phrasing. I'm trying to stay open-minded about this whole situation, and any answers are welcome as long as they don't endorse white supremacy. I'm not trying to beg the question either -- I haven't read the Bible cover-to-cover in a long time and I don't remember whether anybody is ever described as white, so I'm crowdsourcing this.

Comment: The answer to your question is "No" - no one is described as "white".  But then again, no one is described as "black" or "yellow" either.  The only exception is when someone gets leprosy and they are described as "white as snow", eg, Num 12:10,2 Kings 5:27, Ex 4:6, etc

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a quotation:
[From Mission Resource Network:](https://www.mrnet.org/blog-db-1/2021/01/26cbh-s5y6g)

> **Did you know there are no white people in the Bible?** Does that
> surprise you? It’s true, I assure you. Not Adam, Abraham, Moses,
> Deborah, David, Elijah, Jezebel, Daniel, Jesus, Peter, Paul, or even
> Lydia or the church in Rome were white. **Most of the people in the
> Bible were Jews of middle eastern origin. The few people in the Bible
> from the region we now call Europe may have had light-colored skin and
> would be considered white today, but they were not white in their day.**

> How can I say this? Because **the concept of whiteness didn’t exist
> yet.** Since the beginning of recorded history, humans have always
> thought in terms of tribes or nations (as in the Cherokee nation or
> Navajo nation, not a modern nation-state), but **the idea of race is a
> fairly new concept.** The Greek word for nation is “ethnos” (from which
> we get the word “ethnic”) and referred to any group of people with a
> common language, culture, story, and territory...    **Nations or tribes
> were categorized in various ways in the ancient world, as reflected in
> the Bible, but skin color was not one of them.** It’s not that the Bible
> never notes that some nations had darker skin than others, but that is
> an exceedingly rare thing for the writers of scripture to mention. It
> just wasn’t considered a relevant factor for identifying people
> groups.

> Skin color in antiquity was more like hair color is for us today...
> As N.T. Wright once quipped on a podcast, “In the Middle Ages, no one
> in Europe would have called anyone ‘white’ unless they had seen a
> ghost or were dead.”

> Early in U.S. history, neither Jewish, Irish, nor Italian people were
> considered to be white, but now they typically are.

I feel that makes the point. I'll conclude with this. Our modern concept is not the same as it was in ancient biblical times. The Bible doesn't explicitly describe people in racial categories such as "white" or "black." What the Bible does focuses on is primarily ethnic and cultural distinctions. Of course due to the area things took place it's often about ancient Near Eastern societies.

In general, I believe the answer to your question is this: **the Bible describes people based on their relationships, actions, and spiritual and cultural importance rather than their outward appearance.** It does not, explicitly label characters as "white" or any other contemporary racial category.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There are several places in the scriptures that mention skin color. My favorite place is in Numbers 12 (NASB):

> 1 Then Miriam and Aaron spoke against Moses because of the Cushite
> woman whom he had married (for he had married a Cushite woman).

The kingdom of Kush (aka Cush) was associated with Nubia in the Ancient Near East and what the Greeks called "Ethiopia," which is now the northern Sudan. You can search on images of northern Sudanese people to confirm that they aren’t “white” by any stretch of the imagination.

> 9 And the anger of the Lord burned against them and He departed. 10
> But when the cloud had withdrawn from above the tent, behold, Miriam
> was leprous, as white as snow.

This is in ironic punishment for Miriam and Aaron’s rebellion fostered by racism.

> 13 So Moses cried out to the Lord, saying, “God, heal her, please!” 14
> But the Lord said to Moses, “If her father had only spit in her face,
> would she not be put to shame for seven days? Have her shut outside
> the camp for seven days, and afterward she may be received again.”

God relented on Miriam’s punishment, but compared Miriam’s racism to God, as creator of all peoples, colors, and ethnicities, **spitting in her face**!

It's God telling Miriam, "Is that white enough for you?"

People in those times were generally not obsessed with skin color as we are today. Neither is God remotely concerned with "interracial marriage." The Bible teaches us that ALL humanity traces back to Noah's family: Shem, Ham, and Japheth.

There was once a display circling a large room in the Smithsonian of tiles matching human skin colors. It was a smoothly continuous spectrum of human skin color ranging from nearly jet black to nearly porcelain white. One could see that any division between them would be completely arbitrary! One can only say that some people have lighter skin color and others darker. All are beautiful in God's sight.

Comment: Sorry to see that someone down voted this and the original question without comment. One can only assume that their reason is shameful.